# calculating complex numbers - help needed

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Probably it is simple, but I am blind right now and I do not see how to solve this task:

$e^{i \frac{2\pi}{3}}+e^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}}+1$

Comment: Perhaps it helps [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_identity)

Comment: What is the task to be solved?  You just gave us an expression.  What do you want us to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$. Use this formula for $\theta = \dfrac{2\pi}{3}, \dfrac{4\pi}{3}$ and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $z=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$ gives $z+z^2+1=\frac{z^3-1}{z-1}$.

Alternatively: mark all three vectors on the unit circle.